# Removed SID Key and now can't log into PC

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

I removed SID Keys named `S-1-5-18`, `S-1-5-19`, and `S-1-5-20`.

Now I can't log into used Win 10 Pro that I  purchased recently. When I log into my Admin account, screen goes blank after a minute.

Answer (score 2):

Those are system accounts required by the OS. Why did you remove those? You may be able to press F8 at boot and do a system restore to restore the registry entries. If not, you will need to find a boot disk that will allow you to load the registry and recreate the keys.

Comment: F8 i.e. legacy boot menu is disabled by default in Windows 10 and OP would need to use **Shift** + restart method to access advanced boot menus.

Comment: That was stupidity on my part. Thought I had a backup but didn't. I removed them from Users and Groups menu, not registry. I see all 3 in registry in the NT profiles. Recoveries have not worked. I can get to command prompt and Task Mgr thru the recovery menu. Is their a tutorial somewhere on how to load registry and recreate keys. If it weren't for programs I would hate to lose, I wouldn't be asking. Thanks

Comment: Do you have the system restore option in the recovery menu? That would be your best bet.

Comment: Can you tell where exactly you removed those SIDs from?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get logged in again. I'm very lucky. I just kept fiddling around with my user acct and Admin acct in Safe Mode until it finally let me log in with normal boot. I was not hopeful, considering my limited knowledge of Windows and security policies. I'm creating an image now for safe keeping. To your question...I had removed those 3 SID's in Windows Local Users and Groups. They were still there in the Registry though. That, and the fact I could log in with my user acct in Safe Mode gave me some hope. Thanks for your replies. It was greatly appreciated.